# Lost remote access to azure vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I changed the port for RDP on my Azure VM. And now I can't connect to it. Probably because I forgot to set the firewall to allow the new port. And now I can't access to it.

I am not sure if I setup Powershell on that VM before. However, when I use Enter-PSSession and it gave me this error:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 40.xx.xxx.xxx failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By
default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Comment: Did you try changing the port back? If you can't: Did you change the endpoint (or inbound port mappings of the network security group) to map to your new port? In any case: This should be on ServerFault, not StackOverflow (it's not programming-related).

Comment: Thanks. the question is how to change the port back without RDP. I found a tool in portal that can upload a script, which did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add VM's IP address to trusted hosts (on the box you are connecting from.
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "40.xx.xxx.xxx" (or *)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about that this issue is caused by the local firewall of the OS. Then you are able to change the firewall rule by Custom Script extension.

If you are using the ASM mode, please check this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-extensions-customscript/).

If you are using the ARM mode, please check this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-customscript/).

You are able to create a new firewall rule through the powershell command New-NetFirewallRule.

For detailed information about how to manager the windows firewall by powershell, please refer to the link below:

[Network Security Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554906(v=wps.630).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. In the azure port, there is a way to upload a powerscript file to run in the VM. I just used it to change the port back to old 3389 and restart.